# What is known about this sequence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am investigating a modified version of the sieve of Eratosthenes, where instead of eliminating numbers starting with $n$ by adding $n$ each time, which results in the set of primes, $n+m$ is added instead, where $m$ starts from 0 and is incremented by 1 every elimination. My rather poor definition for the set $D$ containing all of these numbers is as follows:

Let $n_1=1, R_1=\mathbb{N}$, where $n_{a+1}=min\left(R_a\setminus\left\{x|x=\frac{1}{2}\left(2n_a\left(k+1\right)+k\left(k-1\right)\right),k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\right)$

Then $D=\left\{y|y=n_b,b\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$

The first few terms in the sequence of numbers in $D$ are as follows:

1,3,5,8,9,12,13,14,17,19,20,27,30,32,33,41,42,44...

My question is essentially: what is currently known about these types of numbers?

### EDIT #1:

---

I have written a few programs to investigate these numbers, and defining $d(n)$ as the number of elements in $D<n$, I have observed that $\frac{d(n)}{n}$ appears to decrease as $n$ is increased, starting from 1. However, since the gap between each elimination starting from some $n\rightarrow+\infty$, I would think that at some point this value may again begin to increase.

Here is a graph of the value $\frac{d(n)}{n}$ for the first 5000 $n$, with $n$ on the x-axis:

[image]

At $n=100,000,000$, $\frac{d(n)}{n}$ decreases from the value of about $\frac{1}{3}$ shown in the graph to roughly $\frac{1}{4}$.

I now have many questions related to these numbers, for example:

- <del>Are there an infinite number of these?</del> (I believe I have shown this)
- Does the value of $\frac{d(n)}{n}$ actually begin to increase again, perhaps tending back towards 1? If so, what would the "turning point" of this be - is it infinite or finite?
- Can every natural number be represented as the difference of two numbers in $D$?
- Where might I find more information on these numbers?

I am first trying to prove (or disprove) that there an infinite number of these, which I believe there are. I have tried applying similar methods as those used to prove there are infinitely many primes, without much success. Any help or pushes in the right direction would be much appreciated!

### EDIT #2:

---

I believe I have a proof that $|D|$ is infinite:

We start with a formula for $a$, the $b$th number "eliminated" by some root $c$: $a=(b+1)c + \frac{1}{2}b(b-1)=\frac{1}{2}(b+1)(b+2c-2)+1$, where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$.

The set $S=\{x:\forall b,c\in\mathbb{N}, x\not =\frac{1}{2}(b+1)(b+2c-2)+1,x\in\mathbb{N}\}$ denotes the set of all "strong" roots. These are roots not eliminated by any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, whereas the set $D$ contains all roots not eliminated by any $d\in D$. Since $D\subset\mathbb{N}$, we can conclude that $S\subset D$.

To determine which numbers are in $S$, we will investigate $a$ such that $a\not=\frac{1}{2}(b+1)(b+2c-2)+1$. First, we let $2k=(b+1)(b+2c-2)$ and look for solutions where $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Substituting $b=2m$ and $c=2^{n-1}+1-m$, where $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, we notice that if $2^n>2m-2$, then $2k=2^n(2m+1)$ is a solution. We also find that if $b=2^n-1$ and $c=m+2-2^{n-1}$, where $2^n<2m+4$, then $2k=2^n(2m+1)$ is also a solution.

Since $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\exists m\in\mathbb{N}:((2^n>2m-2)\lor (2^n<2m+4))$, we can conclude that $\forall b,c\in\mathbb{N}\exists n,m\in\mathbb{N}:(\frac{1}{2}(b+1)(b+2c-2)=2^{n-1}(2m+1))$. Substitution into our original formula yields $a=2^{n-1}(2m+1)+1\implies S$ may only contain numbers of the form $2^{n-1}+1$.

We will now show that all numbers of the form $2^{n-1}+1$ are in $S$. Let us assume that $(b+1)(b+2c-2)=2^n$. Then $b+1\equiv 0\pmod 2\implies b+2c-2\equiv 1\pmod 2$, but $2^n$ cannot have any odd factors other than $1\implies b=c=1$, hence $r=0$, but $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$, and so we have a contradiction $\implies S=\{x:x=2^{r-1}+1,r\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{1\}$.

As there are infinite numbers of the form $2^{n-1}+1$, we know that $|S|$ is infinite, and since $S\subset D$, $|D|\ge |S|$, hence $|D|$ is infinite.

Comment: I had one shining one but I lost it the wrong direction :>

Comment: Not sure I follow the definition.  OEIS doesn't recognize the sequence...are you sure you have followed your rules properly?

Comment: I tried searching on OEIS too and couldn't find anything, so came here. Let me add the diagram I used to think about it on paintbrush (probably won't help much)

Comment: Why is $7$ not in the sequence?

Comment: since 1 -> (1+1=2) -> (2+2=4) -> (4+3=7), so it is "eliminated" by the first wave

Comment: This might be worth adding to the OEIS. I don't exactly know what the protocol for that is now, they changed it a few years ago.

Comment: I wonder if there's infinitely many of these numbers? My guess is there is since the spacing between each elimination is larger than the regular sieve which yields infinite primes

Comment: Your description isn't very clear (and it will need to be if you want to get it into the OEIS $\ddot{\smile}$). Is the idea that if at stage $n$ you have $a_{n,1}, a_{n,2},a_{n,3} \ldots$, then you get to the next stage by deleting $a_{n,1}+a_{n,1}, a_{n,2} +a_{n,1}+1, a_{n,3}+a_{n,1}+2, \ldots$? Or what?

Comment: Agreed, so far all I have is some messy wave patterns I drew when I was bored - let me try and write a somewhat cohesive definition

Comment: But hey, remember how Ulam came up with his spiral...

Comment: +1 for diaphragm. No seriously i probably liked it most because it made me think of xxmas.

Comment: @reuns I've just added my attempt as an edit

Comment: You realize replacing $U_n = \{ nk , k \ge 1\}$ by $V_n= \{ n+ \sum_{m=0}^k (n+m), k \ge -1 \}$ is more than weird. I would be less restrictive and ask the more general question : can we find a way to replace  $U_n$  by "other arithmetic sets $V_n$ of integers" in such a way we can deduce interesting things when sieving the integers using the $V_n$.

Comment: Really? It seems quite natural to me to replace it with a version where the sieve increments each time, perhaps due to my programming background. What sort of sets would you suggest looking at?

Comment: You can look at power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, multiplication of power series is additive ($z^n z^m = z^{n+m})$ and the associated sieving is with $V_n = \{ m \ge n\}$, versus Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$, multiplication of Dirichlet series is multiplicative ($n^{-s} m^{-s} = (nm)^{-s}$) and the associated sieving is with $V_n = \{ m n, m\ge 1\}$. So in some sense the question is "what next" ? See also additive and multiplicative monoids.