# Finding an expression for $\prod_{x=1}^n(1-f(x))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, statistics

### Question:

Say I have $\prod_{x=1}^n(1-f(x))$ where $1 > f(x) > 0$. I am looking to find a way to express this product using $f(x)$.

Expanding gives me $1-\sum(\text{odd pairs})+\sum(\text{even pairs})$, however I am not sure how to reduce further.

### Context:

For the case:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2a+\frac{1}{4}}}$$
this product gives the probability that $a$ isn't eliminated by any $x<a$, related to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491459/what-is-known-about-this-sequence).

Any advice/pointers to useful topics are appreciated!

Comment: The expression you have is "a way to express this product using $f(x)$." What properties do you want the expression to have?

Comment: @StellaBiderman I'd like to be able to express it in closed form using the variables $x$ and $a$

Comment: And $n$? Or is this for fixed $n$?

Comment: Of course it is easy to find the total number of terms using the binomial theorem, but I can't seem to find a "mean" for the products of $k$ pairs of $f(x)$

Comment: Yeah in $n$ as well, it's part of an approximation of a function $d(n)$ which finds the fraction of numbers $<n$ in the sequence I describe in a previous question

Comment: I don't think that such an expression exists.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I didn't think so either, but removing the square root in wolfram alpha gives me: https://imgur.com/a/GgDsP, it just says computation time exceeded when I add the root back in. I'm trying to figure out what algorithm it uses to compute these values to perhaps show it can or cannot be written in a similar way. Some of the graphs it gives me strikingly resemble the weirdness of the real $d(n)$ at similar values, followed by a steep change again around the same region

Comment: You can take a logarithm to get a sum.

Comment: And the connection to statistics is??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's **an** answer:

Define
$$
P = \prod_{m=1}^n\bigl(1 - f(m)\bigr)\, .
$$
Take a natural log of both sides:
$$
\ln P = \sum_{m=1}^n \ln\bigl(1 - f(m)\bigr)
$$
Now use the Taylor series of $\ln(1-x)$
$$
\ln(1-x) \;=\; -x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} - ... \;=\;
-\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}
$$
to get:
\begin{align}
\ln P &= \sum_{m=1}^n \ln\bigl(1 - f(m)\bigr)\\
&= -\sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{{f(m)}^k}{k}\\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{m=1}^n {f(m)}^k
\end{align}
Hence:
$$
P = \exp\left[
-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{m=1}^n {f(m)}^k
\right]
$$
I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing you're looking for, but I doubt there's a simpler general answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I see how this helps with anything, but I suspect the expression you're looking for is
$$1-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\sum_{1\le x_1<\dots<x_k\le  n}\prod_{j=1}^kf({x_j})$$